# Perform groupby calculation on column excluding certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, percentage

```
I have this df:

data = {'A':[102, 102, 102, 102, 312, 312, 312], 
        'B':[1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001,1001],
        'C':[3005,3005,3005,3005,3005,3005,3005],
        'D':[2004,2004,2004,2004,2002,2002,2002],
        'E':[1,3,5,999,1,5,999],
        'F':[300,1,192,837,19,1,1037]} 

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'])

df.head(7)
```

A line of code calculates the percentage which works apart from I want it to exclude the count values where the rows value in column E is (999):

```
df['Percentage'] = 100 * df['F'] / df.groupby('A')['F'].transform('sum')
```

Percentage should show:

```
Percentage
60.85193
0.20284
38.94523
(Blank)
95
5
(Blank)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are df and data two separate dataframes?

Comment: Hi! There are different columns names between your code and the data dataframe

Comment: Edited so is all correct now. Apologies about that one.

Answer (score 0):

Use mask to ignore the rows you want.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': [102, 102, 102, 102, 312, 312, 312],
        'B': [1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001],
        'C': [3005, 3005, 3005, 3005, 3005, 3005, 3005],
        'D': [2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2002, 2002, 2002],
        'E': [1, 3, 5, 999, 1, 5, 999],
        'F': [300, 1, 192, 837, 19, 1, 1037]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])

mask = ~(df['E'] == 999)
df['Percentage'] = 100 * df[mask]['F'] / df[mask].groupby('A')['F'].transform('sum')
```

Output:

```
     A     B     C     D    E     F  Percentage
0  102  1001  3005  2004    1   300   60.851927
1  102  1001  3005  2004    3     1    0.202840
2  102  1001  3005  2004    5   192   38.945233
3  102  1001  3005  2004  999   837         NaN
4  312  1001  3005  2002    1    19   95.000000
5  312  1001  3005  2002    5     1    5.000000
6  312  1001  3005  2002  999  1037         NaN
```

Comment: changed data to df (that was an error by me in the question) this just seems remove the percentage value where E == 999, however it doesn't alter the % value of the other 3 rows to what the question says they should be.

Answer (score 0):

You can subsection your frame and `transform` that particular section, and then reassign the results back:

```
# Get the sub group
>>> grp = df[df['E'].ne(999)]

# Not required: this shows the Intermediate state of the transformed percentage
>>> grp['F'].mul(100).div(grp.groupby('A')['F'].transform('sum'))
0    60.851927
1     0.202840
2    38.945233
4    95.000000
5     5.000000
Name: F, dtype: float64

# Apply the result to your main frame
>>> df['Percentage'] = grp['F'].mul(100).div(grp.groupby('A')['F'].transform('sum'))
```

Result:

```
>>> df
     A     B     C     D    E     F  Percentage
0  102  1001  3005  2004    1   300   60.851927
1  102  1001  3005  2004    3     1    0.202840
2  102  1001  3005  2004    5   192   38.945233
3  102  1001  3005  2004  999   837         NaN
4  312  1001  3005  2002    1    19   95.000000
5  312  1001  3005  2002    5     1    5.000000
6  312  1001  3005  2002  999  1037         NaN
```